# Create new column from another column's particular value using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks like this

| A | B | C | Category | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | Prime | Unique | 0 |
| 2 | A | Prime | One | Initials |
| 1 | A | Prime | Two | Seconds |
| 2 | B | Prime | Unique | 1 |
| 2 | B | Prime | One | Firsts |

I want to create a new dataframe where I group first 3 columns and based on Category value make it new column i.e. If Category has value Unique, Make it a column and add it's value to the correspondings in the group

I want my new dataframe to look like this:

| A | B | C | Category | Value | Unique |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | A | Prime | One | Initials |  |
| 1 | A | Prime | Two | Seconds | 0 |
| 2 | B | Prime | One | Firsts | 1 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First need distingusih which rows are pivoted, here if `Category` is `Unique`, filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and add to original not matched rows by `~` with [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
m = df['Category'].eq('Unique')

#if need test multiple values
#m = df['Category'].isin(['Unique', 'Another val'])

df1 = df[m].pivot(index=['A','B','C'], columns='Category', values='Value')
print (df1)
Category  Unique
A B C           
1 A Prime      0
2 B Prime      1

df = df[~m].join(df1, on=['A','B','C'])
print (df)
   A  B      C Category     Value Unique
1  2  A  Prime      One  Initials    NaN
2  1  A  Prime      Two   Seconds      0
4  2  B  Prime      One    Firsts      1
```

Comment: I think this should do for now, Thankyou it's very helpful :)